# Jackson JsonMappingException: Invalid type id

Tags: java, json, jackson, cxf, fasterxml

I've a model with field annotated as a:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = CLASS)
private Object dudClass;
```

The main problem is when I try to deserialize this object and I don't have this dudClass instance on classpath I will receive an exception:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid type id 'pl.erbel.DudClass' (for id type 'Id.class'): no such class found.
```

Is it any easy way to just ignore this exception? I don't want to ignore serialization/deserialization cause I need this in different module. I just have a two clients: one with DudClass on classpath and the seconde one without that class.

Comment: Have you tried @JsonIgnore?

Comment: Try using transient.

Comment: @Coder if I use JsonIgnore I won't be able to serialize/deserialize that field, will I?

Comment: @Borislav do you mean spring transient annotation?

Comment: JsonIgnore  can we used either on serialization or deserialization alone if you need it that way

Comment: But I don't want to just ignore it. I want to ignore it ONLY if class is not on the classpath and it can't be deserialize...

Comment: will getting that object as an additional property work for you?

Comment: @MarcinErbel no try using the java transient, private transient Object dubClass, this will mark the field as not mandatory for the serializer

Answer (score 2):

It might not be the perfect solution but this is a work around. Instead of having `dudClass` in your POJO you can make use of the additional properties using `JsonAnyGetter` and `JsonAnySetter`. You need to remove the dudClass from your parent class and include the following code

```
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
```

What this does is while deserializing instead of trying to set the dudClass everytime it sets any additional objects that comes along in the response to the  Map with object name as the key (in your case it's dudClass) and the object contents as the value. You just have see if the Map has dudClass key present or not.

Let me know if this doesn't answer your issue or need clarification!